# How to merge data from list Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

i have a list like this one:

> serie_chart = [ { "name":"Bodega", "data":[ 1484617495839, 23 ] }, {
>   "name":"Otro", "data":[ 1484617703695, 30 ] }, { "name":"Camara1",
>   "data":[ 1484622282856, 22 ] }, { "name":"Camara1", "data":[
>   1484622286969, 24 ] }, { "name":"Camara1", "data":[ 1484622289794, 26
>   ] }];

and i want to merge this data like this using the repeated name and store the data into a list

> [
>       {
>       "name":"Bodega",
>       "data":[
>       1484617495839,
>       23
>       ]
>       },
>       {
>       "name":"Otro",
>       "data":[
>       [
>       1484617703695,
>       30
>       ],
>       [
>       1484617998559,
>       33
>       ]
>       ]
>       },
>       {
>       "name":"Camara1",
>       "data":[
>       [
>       1484622282856,
>       22
>       ],
>       [
>       1484622286969,
>       24
>       ],
>       [
>       1484622289794,
>       26
>       ],
>       [
>       1484677105646,
>       55
>       ]
>       ]
>       }
>       ]

I create this code,

```
 var temp = {};
 for (var i=0; i<serie_chart.length; i++) {
     temp[serie_chart[i].name] =
     temp[serie_chart[i].name] === undefined ?
     serie_chart[i].data : [temp[serie_chart[i].name],serie_chart[i].data];
 }
   serie_chart = [];
      for (var key in temp) {
          serie_chart.push({'name': key, 'data': temp[key]})
      }
```

but i dont know what im missing because he created me a lot of lists inside the data when im trying to push it. I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var temp = {};
for (var i=0; i<serie_chart.length; i++) {
    if(!temp[serie_chart[i].name]) {
     temp[serie_chart[i].name]=[];
    }
    temp[serie_chart[i].name].push(serie_chart[i].data);
}
serie_chart = [];
for (var key in temp) {
    serie_chart.push({'name': key, 'data': temp[key]})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is Muhridin Ibragimov answer with enhanced performance, where we iterate over the array one time:

```
var temp = {};
var result = [];
for (var i=0; i<serie_chart.length; i++) {
    var chart = serie_chart[i]
    var name = chart.name
    if(!temp[name]) {
     temp[name]=[];
     result.push({'name': name, 'data': temp[name]})
    }
    temp[name].push(chart.data);
}
```